# Google Sheets array - filling the gaps on irregular data

Tags: charts, google-sheets

I have the following spreadsheet I am looking to solve a somewhat simple problem for:

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EUP_mf8zMS9Be2HSq6TlZ4K0nr6Zggf4hdNJPp7TsRU/edit#gid=2041645299)

`Data` tab contains the irregular data (as seen by the dates)

`Chart 1` tab contains a working chart as I wish it to be presented

`Chart 2` tab contains the new array structure I wish to populate

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to populate cell x,y on the `Chart 2` array when matching x & y from the `Data` tab.  ie - replicating `322` from cell `Data - F3` to cell `Chart 2 - H75` etc

`INDEX` - `MATCH` doesn't work as it references the cell location, not the cell contents - and as the array, I am graphing from is dynamic, this doesn't work.

The intended outcome is to be able to then `QUERY` the resultant data and plot an `Age vs Weight` chart instead of current `Date vs Weight` chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this into **H4** cell and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($G$4:$G, Data!$A$2:$U, 
 IFS(H2="Bear",            2,
     H2="Bwuce",           3,
     H2="Calcifer",        4, 
     H2="Capt. Kwazy Sox", 5,
     H2="Chooie",          6,
     H2="Lil Fibbs",       7,
     H2="Howl",            8,
     H2="JC",              9,
     H2="Jim Rat",        10,
     H2="Milo Jr",        11,
     H2="Sgt. Simba Sox", 12,
     H2="Angel",          14,
     H2="Fern",           15,
     H2="Fuzznut",        16,
     H2="Houdini",        17,
     H2="Kami",           18,
     H2="Mumma Bear",     19, 
     H2="Rosie J",        20,
     H2="Sophie",         21), 0), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: player0 to my rescue again!  Thank you so much <3

Comment: Didn't expect you'd have to hardcode it like that - thanks for all the effort you went to, looks like it would've been a little annoying to get all that together.  I'll test it out very shortly.

My floofs are very excited to see who is growing the fastest.  Unfortunately we only have Capt. Kwazy Sox, Sgt. Simba Sox, Lil Fibbs and Milo Jr still in the competition.  :(

Comment: could be a bit shorter if you replace those names to cells like instead of `H2:"Bear"` it will be `H2=Data!B1`

Comment: It works great - but now the stupid thing is I can't figure out how to transition that data to their respective ages.  I had a misunderstanding of the `OFFSET` function, thinking that I could use that to offset the data down `Date` - `B'day` cells in another table with `Days` replacing the `Date` column.

I'm completely brain dead at the moment :(

Comment: if this question was answered up to your needs then mark the answer as solved. if you have another question, feel free to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask (I would like to advise you but I have no idea what you are trying to offset from your brief summary)

Comment: Sorry I'm still getting used to the rules and expectations of this site, my apologies.

Comment: Marked as answered, upticked, and asked another question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54848525/reformatting-the-array-of-a-date-weight-chart-to-make-it-an-age-weight-chart

Hope I've done it correctly.  Thanks for all your help!