# Reformatting the array of a "Date/Weight" chart to make it an "Age/Weight" chart

Tags: google-sheets

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EUP_mf8zMS9Be2HSq6TlZ4K0nr6Zggf4hdNJPp7TsRU/edit#gid=1140416255)

I have a spreadsheet that tabulates and charts weights that were taken across various dates. I have expanded that to an array that plots the original `Data` sheet values on an expanded `Date` column - as can be seen on the `Chart 2` sheet.

What I am wanting to do now on `Chart 3` is plot the same weight data into an array that has `Age` in days replacing the `Date` column - as can be seen.  I had thought this was a simple process, but I cannot figure it out.

Looking at the column for "Angel" I have determined that the offset for her data is 609 - meaning that cell `T609` should contain the data in cell `H4` as she was 675 days old on the day of that weighing.  I had a misunderstanding that I could `OFFSET` column `H` down `605` rows, but I've discovered that's not how the `OFFSET` function works.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### this solution is able to handle positive and negative offset

```
=IF($G$4-VLOOKUP(T2,$B$2:$C$24,2,0)>0,{ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀", 
 (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(INDEX(H4:H,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((H4:H<>0),0),0)),H:H,0),7,4))-
 VLOOKUP(T2,$B$2:$C$24,2,0))-4-66), "♂")), "♀", "")); H4:H}, 
 {ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀", 
 MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(INDEX(H4:H,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((H4:H<>0),0),0)),H:H,0),7,4))-
 VLOOKUP(T2,$B$2:$C$24,2,0),$S:$S,0)-4), "♂")), "♀", "")); 
 QUERY(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(INDEX(H4:H,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((H4:H<>0),0),0)),H:H,0),
 COLUMN(H1),4)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(H1),4),1,)))})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### this solution can handle only positive offset

and unless the value in **R4** is less than **6**, it will work:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀", R4-4), "♂")), "♀", "")); H4:H}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!  Thank you.  I know nothing about `REGEXREPLACE`, `SPLIT`, or `REPT` so I've got a bit of googling to do to understand this formula.  I'm glad that it wasn't so simple after all.

I've modified the formula to not have to reference `R4` and it works perfectly 

`={ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀", $G$4-$S$4-(VLOOKUP(T2,$B$2:$C$24,2,FALSE))), "♂")), "♀", "")); H4:H}`

EXCEPT for when there isn't a value in `Row4` - Lil Fibbs for example.  In that instance it only offsets the data by one row.

Comment: Oh I see what is wrong.  Lil Fibbs & Sgt. Simba Sox' B'days were AFTER the first weight date.....this should be an easy fix then I hope.

Comment: Oh I thought I had - my bad.  I'll do it now, sorry.